# How do I use shell variables of awk script in system command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am troubleing in coverting hex to decimal from txt file using awk.

I want to do like this

```
awk -F' '   '{   system("echo '$((16#"$1"))'") '} $file_name
```

but not work... then I try other code

```
awk -F' ' -v var="\"echo \x27\$((16#" '{var=var$1"))\x27\"" system(var) }' $file_name
```

also not work. but print var then 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhT69.png)

what should i do?

Comment: Please include content as text, not behind image links. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) -- the reasoning regarding searchability, accessibility, access to folks behind corporate firewalls, bandwidth expenditures, &c. apply for errors as well.

Comment: Also, frankly, using the `system()` command in `awk` is a code smell -- you're **much** better off not using `awk` at all if you'd be pushing all the work from awk back to a shell. `system()` is not just inefficient, but its use runs major security risks.

Comment: @Charless Duffy sorry to upload image links, next time I must upload code, then not using awk, not using system() , As result, What can I use it?

Comment: either awk only, or bash only; John's answer covers both. `system()` is dangerous because everything it passes is parsed as code, so malicious data can run arbitrary commands; you don't have that problem when handling data in bash unless `eval` or equivalents are used, nor do you have it in native awk.

Comment: @Charless Duffy ok, I understand, then I want script code in either awk only or bash only, I don't know using only one way either awk only or bash only

Comment: If you had a *working* mechanism that combined the two, I'm quite sure someone could help you transform it to native awk alone. But it's not remotely clear to me that the code you're saying you "want to do" would actually solve your intended problem even *if* the issues surrounding the use of `system()` were fixed.

Comment: (Personally, by the way, I'd use Python for this job; it has everything in the standard library needed for the task at hand, *specifically* including support for parsing data as signed 64-bit integers).

Comment: @Charles Duffy Wow really? could you show me a sample code?

Comment: I'm about to go to bed right now, but to give you some pointers -- I'd use [`binascii`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html) to convert your data to binary, and then [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to parse it as the specific (signed 64-bit) type you want. Though you could also parse it to an integer, and then use `struct` to serialize that integer as an *unsigned* binary, and then deserialize as a signed value; that way you don't need to worry about padding being exact, as you would with the binascii approach.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you ask a directly on-point question for your real goal *("How can I convert a hex string to a signed 64-bit integer?")*, feel free to @-notify me with a link, and if it doesn't have any good answers in the morning I'll write one up myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using awk

To use GNU awk to convert hex to decimal:

```
$ echo '0xFFFFFFFE' | awk -n '{printf "%i\n",$1}'
4294967294
```

Or:

```
$ x='0xFFFFFFFE'
$ awk -n -v x="$x"  'BEGIN{printf "%i\n",x}'
4294967294
```

Or:

```
$ x='0xFFFFFFFE'; awk -v x="$x"  'BEGIN{print strtonum(x)}'
4294967294
```

To convert hex to decimal using bash:

```
$ echo $((0xFFFFFFFE))
4294967294
```

Limitations:

```
1. GNU awk is limited to 52-bit integers.

2. The above could be extended to perform two's-complement arithmetic but it hasn't.
```

To avoid both these limitations, see the python solution below:

#### Using python

Awk does not handle long integers.  For long integers, consider this python script:

```
$ cat n.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
def h(x):
        x = int(x, 16)
        return x if x < 2**63 else x - 2**64

for line in sys.stdin:
        print(*[h(x) for x in line.split()])
```

Let's use this input file:

```
$ cat file
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF EFEFEFEFEFEFEFEF
```

When we run our script, we find:

```
$ python3 n.py <file
-1 -1157442765409226769
```

Comment: my file's contens are FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF EFEFEFEFEFEFEFEF and I want to read and convert hex to long type(int64)!

Comment: @bestn Are those two numbers on one line or on two lines?

Comment: 2 colums per 1 row and I think I must use echo like "echo $((16#FF))", don't it?

Comment: Then do the same thing using `"$2"` to handle the second field.

Comment: @David C. Rankin yes, I know but I first need to process "$1" then add code "$2"

Comment: @John1024  I want to get data in signed int64 not unsigned type

Comment: You can do the same thing. You are getting I presume a `line` (2 - columns) of data at a time and passing to your script or function as the first argument. It will be seen in you script or function as `$1` (which just happens to be what `awk` uses to represent field-1). In your script or function, just `echo $1 | awk -n '{printf "%i  %i\n", $1, $2}'`

Comment: @David C. Rankin I know... but  if  input data using "%i" is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE, then output is 18446744073709551616, But !!!!!! I want to get "-2"

Comment: @David C. Rankin Key key problem is that converting hex to long(int64)

Comment: Yes, I see that now. The problem I see is you are starting with hex, which is unsigned and you want to not only convert from hex to decimal, but from unsigned to signed. I'll look at the `awk` manual, but do not know the answer to the second cast to signed issue off the top of my head.

Comment: @John1024 How can I use "echo "$((#16$variable))"" in awk?

Comment: @bestn -- yes, yes, I completely agree. It would be relatively trivial in C to handle the conversion. A simple `strtol` on each of the hex values would be sufficient (of course with the proper validations). Just pass the whole string containing both columns to your C program and walk down the string using `nptr` and `endptr` parameters provided by `strtol`.

Comment: @bestn See updated answer for python solution that handles long integers.

Comment: @David C. Rankin  I try c code in this problem, char hex[18] ="FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"; long value = strtol(hex,NULL,16); printf("%lx", value);                                                  output : 7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF          , strtol also isn't appropriate for this problem

Comment: @John1024 AMAZING~! Thank you! god python!

Comment: @bestin if you are still stuck, here is C code that will [Convert your large hex values to signed `int64_t`](https://pastebin.com/tqedMZrd)